# Registration not working in Laravel 5

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-5, phpmyadmin

I am trying to use the validation for a registration page but not getting success, just displaying the same page and no data is getting inserted into the database neither on unique email nor on repeated email. I am doing this in Laravel 5.

Here if my route in `routes.php` file:

```
Route::get('/registration_page', 'makelogin@registration_function');
```

Here is controller

```
public function registration_function(Request $request)
   {
     $nam_value = $request->nam;
     $email_value = $request->r_email;
     $password_value = $request->r_password;
     $city_value = $request->city;

     $this->validate($request, [
       'email' => 'required|unique:registered|max:255',
       'password' => 'required',
     ]);

     $reg=DB::table('registered')->insert(['name' => $nam_value, 'email' => $email_value,
'password'=>$password_value,'city'=>$city_value]);
     return redirect('makelogin_page')->with('status','Registered Successfully');
   }
```

and here is the blade.php file(view)

```
<div class="container">
   <h3>New user ?</h3>
   <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#registration">Register</button>
   <!-- Modal -->
   <div class="modal fade" id="registration" role="dialog">
     <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
       <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
           <h4 class="modal-title">Registration</h4>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
           <p>Please Register Yourself Here</p>
           <form role="form" action="registration_page" method="get">
             <div class="form-group">
               <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nam" placeholder="Your Name Please" style="width:265px;">
             </div>
             <div class="form-group">
               <input type="email" class="form-control" name="r_email" placeholder="Your Email Please" style="width:265px;">
             </div>
             <div class="form-group">
               <input type="password" class="form-control" name="r_password" placeholder="Please enter a password" style="width:265px;">
             </div>
             <div class="form-group">
               <input type="text" class="form-control" name="city" placeholder="Please enter your city" style="width:265px;">
             </div>
             <div class="form-group">
               <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Register">
             </div>
           </form>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Is it showing any error? You have imported Validator and validateRequest?

Comment: not showing any error, just redirecting the same page as I did in controller.

Comment: How could I import Validator and validateRequest ?

Comment: Why you asked exactly same question again?  [signup is unable to validated in laravel 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38913983/signup-is-unable-to-validated-in-laravel-5)

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation , check it out here

Comment: @lorond: I am a new user, I had posted jumbled question, after posted i realised it, the again I maked it proper to read and posted again. Instead of asking the useless question, try to answer the question asked, technically.

Comment: @afshan Shujat: that code is little bit diferent, and I am a new in Laravel, so kindly make correct my code.

Comment: @Pradeep you should edit your existing question instead of asking new one in such cases. You can do it by clicking `edit` right under question's tags. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Here is its route

```
Route::get('/registration_page', 'makelogin@registration_function');
```

Here is its controller

```
> public function registration_function(Request $request)
>     {
>       $nam_value = $request->nam;
>       $email_value = $request->r_email;
>       $password_value = $request->r_password;
>       $city_value = $request->city;
>       $hashed_password = bcrypt($password_value);
>       $valid_user = DB::table('registered')
>                         ->where('email',$email_value)
>                         ->get();
>       if($valid_user)
>       {
>         return redirect('makelogin_page')->with('status_validate','You are already registered with us, Plaese login, Did you forgot your
> password ?');
>       }
>       else
>       {
>         $reg=DB::table('registered')->insert(['name' => $nam_value, 'email' => $email_value,
> 'password'=>$hashed_password,'city'=>$city_value]);
>         return redirect('makelogin_page')->with('status','Registered Successfully');
>       }
>     }
```

And here is its view

```
> <div class="container">
>     <h3>New user ?</h3>
>     <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
>     <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#registration">Register</button>
>     <!-- Modal -->
>     <div class="modal fade" id="registration" role="dialog">
>       <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
>         <div class="modal-content">
>           <div class="modal-header">
>             <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
>             <h4 class="modal-title">Registration</h4>
>           </div>
>           <div class="modal-body">
>             <p>Please Register Yourself Here</p>
>             <form role="form" action="registration_page" method="get">
>               <div class="form-group">
>                 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nam" placeholder="Your Name Please" style="width:265px;" required/>
>               </div>
>               <div class="form-group">
>                 <input type="email" class="form-control" name="r_email" placeholder="Your Email Please" style="width:265px;"
> required/>
>               </div>
>               <div class="form-group">
>                 <input type="password" class="form-control" name="r_password" placeholder="Please enter a password"
> style="width:265px;" required/>
>               </div>
>               <div class="form-group">
>                 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="city" placeholder="Please enter your city" style="width:265px;" required/>
>               </div>
>               <div class="form-group">
>                 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Register">
>               </div>
>             </form>
>           </div>
>           <div class="modal-footer">
>             <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
>           </div>
>         </div>
>       </div>
>     </div>   </div>
```